# Sum of Bill amount in a table and treat duplicate rows with the same bill as same

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In my table I am storing purchase bill of vendors. Like:

```
| Bill No | Vendor | Item | Bill Amount |
| 1929    | abc    | 123  |   840.00    | <-- Treat these as one
| 1929    | abc    | 234  |   840.00    | <-- Treat these as one
| 23874   | xyz    | peo  |  1024.00    |
| 1942    | abc    | pop  |   600.00    |
| 4720    | mno    | test |  1250.00    |
```

I want get the total amount group on vendor where mysql to treat the same bill number as 1 record. Output should be.

```
| Vendor | Total Amount |
| abc    |    1440.00   | <-- It should be 1440 instead of 2280
| xyz    |    1024.00   |
| mno    |    1250.00   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to get the distinct bill numbers and its values in a derived table and then use sum on those values and group by.

Consider the following table

```
mysql> select * from bills ;
+--------+--------+------+-------------+
| billno | vendor | item | bill_amount |
+--------+--------+------+-------------+
|   1929 | abc    | 123  |      840.00 |
|   1929 | abc    | 234  |      840.00 |
|  23874 | xyz    | peo  |     1024.00 |
|   1942 | abc    | pop  |      600.00 |
|   4720 | mno    | test |     1250.00 |
+--------+--------+------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then with the below query we can get the data

```
select 
sum(x.bill_amount) as total_amount,
x.vendor from (
   select distinct billno, vendor , bill_amount from bills 
)x 
group by x.vendor ;


+--------------+--------+
| total_amount | vendor |
+--------------+--------+
|      1440.00 | abc    |
|      1250.00 | mno    |
|      1024.00 | xyz    |
+--------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using SUM() Aggregate:

```
SELECT 
      Vendor,
      SUM([Bill Amount]) AS [Total Amount]
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY [Bill No],Vendor
```